# Prevent TextWrangler for changing search

Tags: google-chrome, search, textwrangler

Every time I switch from TextWrangler to my browser and then do a page search for something (e.g. <kbd>command-F</kbd>) whatever I search for in Chrome is automatically plunked into my search box when I switch back to TextWrangler.

Is there a way to turn this off? I can't seem to find an option for it in the preferences. It's been driving me crazy for years.

Comment: most apps do it - populate from the current copy buffer

Comment: If you search for something it goes in the copy buffer? I assumed that only happened when you actually copied something.

Comment: hmm… you're right, sorry. I'm so used to copy/pasting search terms I didn't actually spot the difference in your question. I'm seeing the same thing with Safari, BBEdit & EasyFind - all behaving the same way. It's not the copy buffer, it must be some other 'find' buffer which is definitely repopulating across different Find functions. Same is seen if I search in any of them, then do a Find in either of the others.

Answer (score 1):

I've found several references to the Mac having a separate Find buffer, but none as to how to turn it off, selectively or otherwise.

Simple overview from [Using the Mac OS X Find Buffer for Text Navigation](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/using-the-mac-os-x-find-buffer-for-text-navigation/)

> Mac OS X has a nifty text feature where you can hit Command-E, and your selection will be placed into a find buffer. Hitting Command-G and Shift-Command-G will find the next or previous instance of your selection.
>
> I find this really useful when poking around in code. For instance if I want to go look somewhere else in a file, I will select a unique chunk of code, and stash it in the find buffer. I go about my business and then as soon as I need to go back, I just hit Command-G. It’s one of those basic little things that really makes working on a Mac quite enjoyable.

Qt reference page - http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/qclipboard.html#Mode-enum
&
Sublime Forum https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6986